# ASP.NET download email attachment through the MemoryStream failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, email-attachments, memorystream

On the server side, I have a file containing an XML serialization of a standard `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` which may contain attachments.
I designed a form to allow users to download these attachments.

Attachment download is controlled by the following code:

```
private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] _buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    using (MemoryStream _ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int _read;

        while ((_read = input.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            _ms.Write(_buffer, 0, _read);
        }

        return _ms.ToArray();
    }
}


protected void bntViewAttachment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _filename = Request.QueryString["file"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_filename))
    {
        MailMessage _message = MailMessageSerializer.Create(Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), OUTBOUND_FOLDER)), _filename));

        try
        {

            int _selected = lbAttachments.SelectedIndex;

            if (_selected != -1)
            {
                Attachment _attachment = _message.Attachments[_selected];

                byte[] _data = ReadFully(_attachment.ContentStream);

                if (_data.Length > 0)
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(_attachment.Name);
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}", _attachment.Name));
                    Response.BinaryWrite(_data);
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Attachment empty";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Exception : " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The email message file is provided by `Request.QueryString["file"]`. Of course, this is not the safest way to operate, but right now I have a bigger problem since the download doesn't work at all... since `_data.Length == 0` all the time.
`lbAttachments` is the `ListBox` showing on the form attachments found inside the mail message.

I can attach an example message XML with a single attachment file [here](https://mega.nz/file/VpoXwKZb#r7eK0P9PHsN42OMSQQQrC5cPLTWO38L5aAw8-AoQK4w).

I'm pretty sure about almost any line of the code since I used them in many other cases, but for some reason it does not here.

Where's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the position on the `ContentStream` must be reset on to its origin.

Adding

```
input.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

on top of

```
private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
```

Will fix it.

Now the problem is probably the encoding of the stream write on the client. At first glance, it looks like the exact attachment data that's contained inside the original mail XML file (and thus `Base64` or something like that).